# Call to undefined method EE_Form_validation::error_array()

Tags: validation

I've updated EE from 2 to 5. I've a custom module where I need to validate a form. In the new EE 5 the function $this->EE->form_validation->error_array() does not exist anymore. I'm using it in the following function:

```
$this->EE->session->set_flashdata(
    'result_message',array(
        'post' => $_POST, 
        'errors' => this->EE->form_validation->error_array()
    )
);
```

Does someone has an answer for this?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used that legacy library in quite a while, but after a quick review of the code in EE 4.3.6 (which should be the same as 5.0.x), I think you can return a string of error messages like so for a Control Panel flash message:

```
...
'errors' => ee()->form_validation->error_string()
...
```

That class and function lives in `system/ee/legacy/libraries/Form_validation.php` and should return a carriage-returned string of errors you can use.

Remember that EE2 was running heavily on a version of CodeIgniter 2.x that EllisLab was maintaining, and in later versions of EE they stopped using that framework as a base. That framework is where the validation class originated, but now (in at least EE4 and EE5) they use a legacy library that has no dependencies on CodeIgniter anymore, so you can only use what lives in that legacy library file.

**I think**. Someone correct me if I'm wrong.